# Import-Csv too Slow

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I currently have a PowerShell script that will import a CSV file and then filter the 1st column to remove the whole row if the row exceeds a certain time.  However, using `Import-Csv` takes a very long time.  Is there a different way to achieve the same result without using `Import-Csv`?

Here is the script at the moment:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Results\*.csv"

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $csv = Import-Csv $file

    $dateTime = $csv[0]."Date and Time"

    $startTime = $dateTime.Substring($dateTime.get_Length()-8)

    $endTime = $startTime
    [int]$hour, [int]$min, [int]$sec = $endTime.Split(':')

    $hour = $hour + 1
    $min = 44
    $sec = 59

    $csv | ForEach-Object {
        $lineTime = $_."Date and Time"
        $startTime = $lineTime.Substring($lineTime.get_Length()-8)
        $newHour, $newMin, $newSec = $startTime.Split(':')
        if (($newHour -lt $hour -and $newMin -gt $min) -or ($newHour -eq $hour -and $newMin -le $min)) {
            $_ | Export-Csv -Path "C:\PerfResults\NewFiles\$filename-NEW.csv" -Append 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As requested by Olaf, below is an example of the data within the CSV file:

```
Date and Time   Memory Overcommit (1 Minute Avg)    Memory Overcommit (5 Minute Avg)    Memory Overcommit (15 Minute Avg)   Cpu Load (1 Minute Avg) Cpu Load (5 Minute Avg) Load (15 Minute Avg)    Physical Cpu(0)\% Processor Time
07/24/2018 14:45:03 0   0   0   0.11    0.13    0.11    7.31
07/24/2018 14:45:06 0   0   0   0.11    0.13    0.12    1.41
```

Comment: You might post a few lines of your csv file as well (formatted as code as well please ;-) ).
It will probably speed up your code when you "collect" the results first in a custom object and export it all together at the end. Using `-Append`is really slow because of the necessary file system operation under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Olaf, the csv files that I am working with have ~12500 columns and 1800 rows so posting lines may be a bit difficult.

Comment: So you should shorten the rows to the relevant columns and pick 3 or 4 lines of this. And of course you should obfuscate sensitive information if needed.

Comment: I've attached an example of the date that the file contains, not sure how to change the format so each data entry is shown under the column name.

Comment: Don't worry - it's ok. Give me some minutes, please.  ;-)

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking your time to look into this :)

Comment: 12500 columns in a CSV is insane. Why are you using a CSV instead of a database for holding these data?

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with DateTime objects you should tread them as such. You can calculate or even compare them much easier than as strings. That will make your life much easier I think. It will be faster when you first collect all data you need and then save them to a file in once.

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem "C:\Results\*.csv"

foreach($file in $fileList) {
    $csv = Import-CSV -Path $file.FullName -Delimiter "`t"
    $NewData = foreach($Data in $csv){
        $Data |
            Select-Object -Property *,
                                    @{
                                        Name = 'NewDateAndTime';
                                        Expression = {
                                            $DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($($Data.'Date and Time'),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null)
                                            $DateTime.AddHours(-4)
                                        }
                                    }
    }
    $NewData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\PerfResults\NewFiles\$($file.BaseName)-NEW.csv" -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

If you don't need all data from the input csv in your output csv you can pick the ones you need with the `Select-Object`.

Edit: additional explanation - I converted the "string" date and time from the csv file to a `DateTime` object with a calculated property. Then I just substracted 4 hours to show how to calculate with `DateTime` objects. Of course you should adapt it to your special needs.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The files now generate much quicker, however the script you have provided does not match the formatting that my original script creates.  In your script it appears to write all of the data to the first column and then just 4 rows instead of seperating each data entry into seperate cells.  Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: ooops ... you're right. I forgot the `-Delimiter`. I corrected the code in my answer. Try it now. I usually use the comma as delimiter ...

Comment: Now that I have added the delimiter to this script and the format is correct, there is no difference in the time it takes to process the file.  It's still taking ~4 mins to generate the "-NEW" csv file.  Is there an alternative to using 'Import-CSV'? 'Get-Content' possible?

Comment: hmmm ... 4 mins for about 12500 columns and 1800 rows doesn't sound that bad to me.  ;-) Does it matter actually? Do you have to wait for it or can it run for itself in the background?

Comment: If possible I would like to complete the process quicker than that, i've got 100's of files to process and this is just the first filter I need to perform, after I remove the time rows I do not need, I also need to delete columns from the file as well.

Comment: That's what I meant before. You could do the manipulation you need in one big chunk inside the loop and write the completed data afterwards in once to a new file.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I'll give that a go now.